# StructureMap Auto registration for generic types using Scan

Tags: c#, structuremap

I've got an interface:

```
IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
```

while im knocking up my UI im using some fake repository implementations that just return any old data.

They look like this:

```
public class FakeClientRepository : IRepository<Client>
```

At the moment im doing this:

```
ForRequestedType<IRepository<Client>>()
   .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<FakeRepositories.FakeClientRepository>();
```

but loads of times for all my IEntities. Is it possible to use Scan to auto register all my fake repositories for its respective IRepository?

Edit: this is as far as I got, but i get errors saying the requested type isnt registered :(

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
    x.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<FakeRepositories.FakeClientRepository>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>));
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
});
```

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this.  Please see this blog posting for details: [Advanced StructureMap: connecting implementations to open generic types](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/18/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/)

```
public class HandlerRegistry : Registry
{
    public HandlerRegistry()
    {
        Scan(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
            cfg.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<FakeRepositories.FakeClientRepository>();
            cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
        });
    }
}
```

Doing it this way avoids having to create your own `ITypeScanner` or conventions.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516955), thats exactly what I needed. For clarity, heres what I did from your link:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
        x.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<FakeRepositories.FakeClientRepository>();
    x.With<FakeRepositoryScanner>(); 
});


private class FakeRepositoryScanner : ITypeScanner
{
    public void Process(Type type, PluginGraph graph)
    {
        Type interfaceType = type.FindInterfaceThatCloses(typeof(IRepository<>));
        if (interfaceType != null)
        {
            graph.AddType(interfaceType, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this discussion from the StructureMap users group: http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/thread/649f5324c570347d

Comment: cool, looks like its the right thing, ill check it out tomorrow