# Using structuremap to Register Generic Types

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am new to structuremap. I am trying to get Structuremap to auto-register

```
public void RegisterAllEventHandlers()
{
    Scan(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
            //cfg.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<NewCustomerCreated>();
            cfg.IncludeNamespace("ParentNameSpace");
            cfg.AddAllTypesOf(typeof (IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>));
        });

        //For(typeof (IHandle<>)).Use(typeof (NewCustomerCreated));
}
```

`NewCustomerCreated` is the event and I want to register all Handlers for this event ie ones  using `IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>`

The following code is working but  I am sure there it can be done by scanning :-

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {                                                      
        x.For(typeof(IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>))
            .Add(new NewCustomerCreatedHandler());                                                                        
        x.For(typeof(IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>))
            .Add(new SendWelcomeEmailToNewCustomer());
    });
```

I am trying to use DomainEvent raiser from 
http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2009/08/better-domain-event-raiser.html

** I would appreciate if someone can edit the question to reflect what I am asking in a better way **

Thank you,

Mar

Edit 1: Adding Code from blog

```
 public interface IEventDispatcher
    {

        void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent;

    }


    public static class DomainEventDispatcher
    {

        public static IEventDispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }



        public static void Raise<TEvent>(TEvent eventToRaise) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
        {

            Dispatcher.Dispatch(eventToRaise);

        }

    }


    public class StructureMapEventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
    {

        public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
        {

            foreach (var handler in ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<TEvent>>())
            {

                handler.Handle(eventToDispatch);

            }

        }
```

From my test project I am calling registry class which will scan the assembly

```
  public void RegisterAllEventHandlers()
        {
            Scan(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
                cfg.IncludeNamespace("Project1");
                //cfg.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>));
                cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));

            });

            // This initializes correctly 
            //ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            //{
            //    x.For(typeof(IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>)).Add(new NewCustomerCreatedHandler());

            //}); 



          // Handler  returns 0 count 

          var handler =ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<NewCustomerCreated>>();





        }
```

and then

```
var eventDispatcher = new StructureMapEventDispatcher();
            DomainEventDispatcher.Dispatcher = eventDispatcher;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cfg.AddAllTypesOf(typeof (IHandle<>));
```

Then your container will do the rest:

```
var handler = container.GetInstance<IHandler<NewCustomerCreated>>();
```

If you need more control take a look at this: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516892/structuremap-auto-registration-for-generic-types-using-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516892/structuremap-auto-registration-for-generic-types-using-scan/519664#519664)

Comment: The handler is still returning empty. Is there any way to find all instances that were added to teh container while calling AddAllTypesOf ?

Comment: I think I was initializing it wrong. I had to do ObjectFactory.Initialize(init => { init.AddRegistry<DomainRegistry>(); });  and then things started working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Being a structuremap newbie I want to make sure that adding the above code was the right procedure and not just some hack that got it working. Thanks