# Integrating StructureMap and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, structuremap

I have

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
{
}
```

and its implementation, EfRepository is like

```
public partial class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    ....
}
```

my MVC Controller factory class:

```
 public class IoCControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

So in autofac I can do something like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).
        InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

How can I do the same in StructureMap?  I don't want to have to to generate all repository classes and declare like below:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
    x.For<IRoleRepository>().Use<RoleRepository>();
    x.For<IWebSiteRepository>().Use<WebSiteRepository>();
    .....
}
```

I have tried this, but no luck

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //      BootStrapper.ConfigureDependencies();
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {

            x.For<IDatabaseFactory>().Use<DatabaseFactory>();

            x.Scan(y =>
            {
               y.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IRepository<>));
                y.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>)).
                    OnAddedPluginTypes(z => z.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());

            });

            x.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<EFUnitOfWork>();

            //services

            x.For<ICategoryService>().Use<CategoryService>();

        });
        try
        {
            ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
        catch (StructureMapConfigurationException ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new IoCControllerFactory());
    }
```

my service class:

```
 public partial class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;      
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public CategoryService(IRepository<Category> categoryRepository, IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this._categoryRepository = categoryRepository;        
        this._uow = uow;
    }   

    public IList<Category> GetAllCategories(Func<Category, bool> expression)
    {
        return _categoryRepository.FindMany(expression).ToList();
    }

}
```

always get the error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily IoC.Repository.IRepository`1[[IoC.Model.Catalog.Category, IoC.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], IoC.Repository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

on the Controllerfactory class

Line 13:         protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
Line 14:         {
Line 15:             return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
Line 16:         }
Line 17:     }

Source File: E:\HCPanel\HCPanel.Web\IoCControllerFactory.cs    Line: 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from:
[StructureMap Auto registration for generic types using Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516892/structuremap-auto-registration-for-generic-types-using-scan)

[Advanced StructureMap: connecting implementations to open generic types](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/17/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types.aspx)

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
     x.Scan(cfg => 
                  {
                      cfg.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IRepository<>));
                      cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>))
                         .OnAddedPluginTypes(y => y.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped())
                  });
});
```

Edit:

Try:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
     x.Scan(cfg =>
                   {
                       cfg.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
                   });
});
```

Comment: it's weird, same error. dont know why. I'm using version 2.6.2

Comment: @Nam - Can you send me a small sample solution that you're having difficulty with, phillip.haydon [at] gmail.com, I haven't had any issues getting it working but maybe i can take a look and send it back to you in a working state.

Comment: Thanks alot, now it's working, weird i tried that whole day but always fail. Again, you're so nice being calm with me. Happy day.

Comment: By the way, can structuremap generates all the repository classes automatically like autofac?. http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/ project uses Autofac and it doesn't need to create a single IRepository and concrete classes. Say like ICategoryRepository and CategoryRepository

Comment: @Nam - Wow, the DependencyRegistrar class in that project is terrible. I use Autofac at home, StructureMap at work, with SM, we create a registry in our repositories project which just scans that 1 assembly for anything that ends in 'Repository' and use the method above: 'RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface', to register them all. We don't have a generic 'IRepository', because I believe having such an interface forces all your repositories to expose methods that aren't required. (some repositories should never delete, for example)