# split cs files, create interfaces and then remove implementations to other project

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have two projects: `DataProj` and `DomainProj`. he current state of my solution is that in DomainProj I have .cs files with two classes in each file: `class X` and `class XRepository`. For example, I have file calles `Customer.cs` and it contains:

```
public class Customer {
...
}

public class CustomerRepository {
...
}
```

I am looking a way to:
1. Split the files so that each class will be in its own file.
2. Create interfaces for each Repository class.
3. Move the Repository classes into DataProj project.
4. Create code for StructureMap that will map each interface to its implementation.

Are there any tools that allow me do this simply? Is there any fast wat I can do it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) from JetBrains is a fantastic tool for doing almost all of this.

With ReSharper installed, click on the class name in the file and then hitting F6 will allow you to move classes within a file into seperate files/folders/projects etc... This will solve points 1 and 3.

Resharper will also allow you to extract an interface by right clicking on the the class and selecting refactor->Extract interface. You will then have the option to choose which methods and properties to extract to the interface. Solves point 2...

The documentation for resharper is great, and if you download the "Cheat Sheet" for the keyboard shortcuts, you should be able to work out most things you need to do.

Not too familiar with StructureMap so unsure on that one...

Comment: But I have to do it for each file and I hav many files like this. Is there any shourtcut for entire folder or project?

Comment: Yes, if you select the folder in Solution Explorer within visual studio and then hit F6 (IDEA shortcut scheme) it will allow you to perform the action on all the code files within that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The structuremap question is basically a duplicate of the question/answer found here:

[StructureMap Auto registration for generic types using Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516892/structuremap-auto-registration-for-generic-types-using-scan)

You do not need to create code that maps your interfaces to concrete classes.  StructureMap already provides that capability.  You simply need to scan